# Blocking a botting URL to an Linux server running Apache

Tags: linux, dns, apache-http-server, blocking, iptables

I have a webserver running OpenSUSE 11.1 and I need to block a URL.  The reason I want to block a URL is because it seems to have a different IP address all the time, but the URL stays the same.

I'd rather not install any new software, so I was hoping for a way to do this with either IPTABLES or Apache.

Would something like this work?

```
iptables -A INPUT -s botmasterlabs.net -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d botmasterlabs.net -j DROP
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iptables` will resolve the name at the time the firewall is loaded.  It won't work for servers with dynamic addresses such as you are encountering.  If the problem site had a static address, you would only need the INPUT rule.

Apache rewrite should be able to do this, but will cost you a DNS lookup for each request the server responds to.  Install a caching DNS server if you don't already have one.  Something light-weight like `dnsmasq` should be sufficient for a smaller site.  Something like the following should forbid access.  See the [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) for additional guidance.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_HOST}  example\.com$
 RewriteRule   * - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks. Close to what I decided to use. I used http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#filesmatch and denied access.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use something like this in your Apache config for the virtual host in question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch /folder(.*) http://is.gd/8BhjPN
```

Does that work for you? Note: that redirect target may not be the exact message you want to give - you may want to throttle that up or down depending on the full context of the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I decided to use http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#filesmatch and deny access.